# How do I query AWS DynamoDB in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nosql

I'm fairly new to NoSQL and using AWS DynamoDB. I'm calling it from AWS Lambda using python 2.7
I'm trying to retrieve a value from an `order_number` field.
This is what my table looks like(only have one record.):
[image]

primary partition key: subscription_id
[image]

and my secondary global index: order_number
[image]

Is my setup correct?
If so given the order_number how do I retrieve the record using python?
I can't figure out the syntax to do it.
I've tried

```
response = table.get_item( Key = {'order_number': myordernumber} )
```

But i get:
`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema: ClientError`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

DynamoDB does not automatically index all of the fields of your object.  By default you can define a hash key (`subscription_id` in your case) and, optionally, a range key and those will be indexed.  So, you could do this:

```
response = table.get_item(Key={'subscription_id': mysubid})
```

and it will work as expected.  However, if you want to retrieve an item based on `order_number` you would have to use a `scan` operation which looks through all items in your table to find the one(s) with the correct value.  This is a very expensive operation. Or you could create a Global Secondary Index in your table that uses `order_number` as the primary key.  If you did that and called the new index `order_number-index` you could then query for objects that match a specific order number like this:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

response = table.query(
    IndexName='order_number-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('order_number').eq(myordernumber))
```

DynamoDB is an very fast, scalable, and efficient database but it does require a lot of thought about what fields you might want to search on and how to do that efficiently.

The good news is that now you can add GSI's to an existing table.  Previously you would have had to delete your table and start all over again.

Comment: thanks for your help, i tried the query code you gave me and its giving me a `global name 'Key' is not defined` and its referring to that line of code you gave me `KeyConditionExpression=Key('order_number').eq(myordernumber))`

Comment: This is what my function looks like `def getRecord( self, table_name, indexName, gsiKey, gsiValue):
  table = self.dynamodb.Table( table_name )
  response = table.query(IndexName=indexName,KeyConditionExpression=Key(gsiKey).eq(gsiValue))`

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I was only importing boto3 but needed to do `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
`

Comment: ^^ . Would be great if this comment is included in the answer :)

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you've imported this:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
```

If you don't have it, you'll get the error for sure. It's in the [documentation examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html).

Thanks @altoids for the comment above as this is the correct answer for me. I wanted to bring attention to it with a "formal" answer.

Answer (score 9):

To query dynamodb using Index with filter:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region)
table = dynamodb.Table('<TableName>')

response = table.query(
    IndexName='<Index>',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('<key1>').eq('<value>') & Key('<key2>').eq('<value>'),
    FilterExpression=Attr('<attr>').eq('<value>')
)

print(response['Items'])
```

If filter is not rquired then don't use `FilterExpression` in query.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the `&`  operator syntax in the `KeyConditionExpression`

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region_name)
table = dynamodb.Table(tableName)

def queryDynamo(pk, sk):
    response = table.query(
        ProjectionExpression="#pk, #sk, keyA, keyB",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#pk": "pk", "#sk": "sk"},
        KeyConditionExpression=
            Key('pk').eq(pk) & Key('sk').eq(sk)
    )
    return response['Items']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the boto3 dynamodb **client**, you can do the following (again you would need to use subscription_id as that is the primary key):

```
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = dynamodb.query(
    TableName='recurring_charges', 
    KeyConditionExpression="subscription_id = :subscription_id",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":subscription_id": {"S": "id"}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is the cleanest way I've discovered; the `query` is in `JSON` format.

```
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def query_items():
    arguments = {
        "TableName": "your_dynamodb_table",
        "IndexName": "order_number-index",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "order_number = :V1",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":V1": {"S": "value"}},
    }
    return dynamodb_client.query(**arguments)
```