# KeyConditions and KeyConditionExpression fail in Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to modify the lambda-microservice example to submit a GET query to dynamodb from an aws-api-gateway. I have gotten the example to work but it does a table scan, not a query.

The query fails trying to set the KeyConditionExpression with the following message:
"Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: name 'Key' is not defined."

The relevant python is here:

```
     operations = {
         'GET': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.query(**x),
     }

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    params = {
    'KeyConditionExpression': Key('flight').eq("2002")     
    }

table = dynamodb.Table('Test')
response = table.query(params)
```

This query form is the same one that worked in this posting:

```
[Working query][1]
```

and I got the same error above.

Alternatively, I get a different error when I try to set the KeyConditions:
"Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.. "

The relevant python is here:

```
    params = {
    'TableName': 'Test',
    'KeyConditions': {
        "flight": {
            'ComparisonOperator': "EQ",
            'AttributeValueList': [{'S': '2002'}]
        }
    }
}
```

My table (Test) has a GSI index, flight-index, with flight as a partition key and the items (all type string) are simply these:

[image: Test table items]

A different post said: "KeyConditionExpression is not supported with nodejs SDK." Is there any similar problem with my using Python 3.7?

Also I am not running DynamoDB local. (I'm grasping at straws for clues.)

As simple as this whole test case is, I must be missing something awfully simple, but I have struggled for several days and read dozens of posts to find it.

Can someone help make either of these ways of specifying the query target work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of different issues that complicated my problem. I presume no one answered because there wasn't an obvious fix.

What I had to do:

- Import Key python library:
  Many thanks to @user3303554 for the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171563) to import Key `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key`
- DynamoDB query permission:
  That finally gave me an AccessDeniedException that showed my lambda function did not have permission to query DynamoDb. Many additional thanks to @Lisa M Shon in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003383) for pointing me to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html because that showed that the microservice example I started modifying had read/write perms, but it did not have a query perm. Added that to the role, and it worked like a charm.

Hopes this helps somebody else just trying to do a simple DynamoDB query.

Comment: Import Key is the winner here - I too was struggling with this.